# SCIP: About the "SCIP_ReaderData" in the bin packing example

Tags: c++, c, scip

A quesion about the reader plugin defined in the binpacking example. I found the following declaration in the interface method (file reader_bpa.c),

```
 SCIP_READERDATA* readerdata;
 readerdata = NULL;
```

I know SCIP_READERDATA is defined in file type_reader.h:

```
typedef struct SCIP_ReaderData SCIP_READERDATA;
```

However, the struct SCIP_ReaderData is not defined in the binpacking reader, so which is the actual struct that "SCIP_READERDATA* readerdata;" reference to? what kind of pointer is readerdata?

PS: I noticed that the default readers in SCIP have similar usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is more a C-question than a SCIP question if I am not mistaken. The interface functions SCIPincludeReader() and SCIPincludeReaderBasic() require a pointer to reader data as last argument. Reader data is supposed to allow the plugin author to connect arbitrary data with their reader plugin by declaring the corresponding `struct SCIP_ReaderData` as many other plugins do.
If you try to do anything with the pointer, e.g., allocate memory for it using `SCIPallocMemory(scip, &readerdata)`, you will get compiler errors because the pointer refers to **an incomplete type**, namely `struct SCIP_ReaderData`.

More useful information on incomplete types is found, e.g., [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjals/index.html)

The point is, the example uses this to make it clearer which arguments are passed to the `SCIPIncludeReaderBasic()`-function, where you would see  `NULL` otherwise.